# PHPWord and O365 / Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, phpword, microsoft365

I want to integrate my PHP App with Microsoft Word in Office 365.
Will the PHPWord package enable integration with Microsoft Office 365 Word.
Does this use Microsoft Graph.
If not is there another way to approach this?

Comment: What does "integrate" mean? Get a list of links? Generate and upload documents? Make edits to existing documents? On the other side, have you read any of the documentation for PHP Word? Have you searched online for resources at all?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Functionality required is to generate a word document and populate it with data from database, so mail merge style functionality but also the ability to store and edit documents produced